# Previewing an iOS document in Finder, without writing a Mac quicklook plugin

Tags: ios, macos, icloud, quicklook

I'm creating a document based app only for iOS. 
The document is saved as a NSBundle which contains a 'thumbnail.png'.

**How to quicklook this iOS document on OSX, so that the 'thumbnail.png' is shown in Finder?**

---

I can see all my iCloud documents in Finder. At the moment I have around 90 documents, so I would like to QuickLook them, to make debugging easier.

```
/Users/johndoe/Library/Mobile Documents/1234ABCDEF~com~johndoe~johndoeapp/Documents/
```

Perhaps there a special naming convension that indicates that 'thumbnail.png' is the
file that QuickLook should show.

Perhaps it's not possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a naming convention to allow you to place static files in your bundle.

From the docs

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Articles/QLImplementationOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005020-CH6-SW3

> If you want to specify static thumbnail and preview images for a
>   bundled document, you can take the easiest approach—it doesn’t even
>   require a generator. Just have your application place the images
>   inside the document bundle in a subfolder named QuickLook; the image
>   file for thumbnails should be named Thumbnail.ext and the file for
>   previews should be named Preview.ext (where ext is an extension such
>   as tiff, png, or jpg). If you decide on this approach, you should not
>   create a generator.

and from experience its case sensitive.

So in your bundle just add a subfolder **QuickLook** and in that folder place **Preview.pdf** or **jpg** or **png**

Comment: Test.document/QuickLook/Preview.png worked in first attempt. Thank you.